# faculty interviews - timing/conflicts

Tags: interview, assistant-professor

I was interviewed on-campus for an assistant professor position and was told that I would be contacted this week for the result. Yesterday, I received an on-campus interview from another university to be done in 3 weeks. I am excited about both positions and do not know how to respond the second invitation. If the first institution offers the position, I am going to accept it as they will not wait for my decision for a couple of more weeks. But I also want to see my chance and the possible offer of the other university. I just don't want to spend their time and resources for me if I receive an offer from the first university. Is it possible to ask for an accelerated interview by telling the truth? or any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: How did this end up working out for you? Any advice to others who might be facing a similar situation?

Answer (score 12):

You can ask for an earlier interview, but they may have already scheduled someone for that time block and may not be able to accommodate the request.

As far as the resources go, it’s definitely an “early bird gets the worm” situation when it comes to faculty hires. Schools that delay their interviews run the risk of losing out on good candidates. So I would proceed on good faith: accept the interview, but let them know ASAP if you receive another offer that you intend to accept.

Comment: I'd even go so far as to ask for an earlier interview date.  Candidates who try to delay the interview process (in hopes that they'll get an offer from their preferred institution) are a bother to hiring committees, but committees like candidates who are eager to interview as soon as possible.  In general, you can interpret it as a sign that a candidate is interested in your offer when they ask for an early interview date and as a sign that they'd rather get a different offer if they put off the interview as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Having at least two interviews and offers works in your favor for both negotiation purpose and speeding purpose. If you get verbal or written offer letter from first university, you can mention it to second university at the end of the interview so they will speed up if they don’t want to miss you. Also, you can ask a few weeks of extension for offer letter from the first university without mentioning you are being interviewed in second university. You can mention some factors such as moving decisions, and family decisions behind the extension to the first university. They may honor your request if they are willing to hire you.

Once you receive both offers you can decide where you wanna go. And even negotiate for salary, other benefits, startup funding, and so on. It’s not uncommon to accept one offer and decline others or even decline one of the two accepted offers. Just be professional when declining and communicating with people. You may meet them again or may not as well. Who knows!